# matching string with a string templating

Tags: php

I have a sting in a var:

`$s = "track order {ordernumber}";`

and I get user input which is:

`$user_input = "track order 1234";`

what i want to do is that i want to match the users' input with the string that i already have and extract the `1234` and save it in the var `$extVar['ordernumber']`

I tried using regex but i was only able to match the static query and was not able to extract the value from the users' string.

This above vars are just for example, the code i'm trying to write should also work on this sort of query as well.

`$s = "{name} wants his order number {onb} to be {req}"`

`$user_input = "haseeb wants his order number 12345 to be canceled/tracked"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplest one and tricky one.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/60GVUc/1)

**Regex:** `(?<=})[^{]+`

> **1.** `(?<=})` negative look behind for `}`
>
> **2.** `[^{]+` match all except `{`

This will match all string which are in between `}` and `{`. **Eg:** `} some words {`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/799985)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$user_input = "haseeb wants his order number 12345 to be canceled/tracked";
$string = "{name} wants his order number {onb} to be {req}";

preg_match_all("#(?<=})[^{]+#", $string, $matches);

$keys=preg_split("/".implode("|",array_map('preg_quote', $matches[0]))."/", $string);
$values=preg_split("/".implode("|",array_map('preg_quote', $matches[0]))."/", $user_input);
print_r(array_combine($keys, $values));
```

Comment: I know how this site works :), I waiting on other peoples responses and utilizing the other answer as well for my solution. i will update this thread once i get a good solution. thank you for your answer though

Answer (score 1):

Your first case could be solved using:

```
preg_match("/^track order (?<order>.*)/", "track order 1234", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Second case could be solved using:

```
preg_match(
    "/^(?<name>.*) wants his order number (?<order>\d*) to be canceled\/tracked/", 
    "haseeb wants his order number 12345 to be canceled/tracked",
    $matches
);
var_dump($matches);
```